# Spring 3 Autowired annotation not working

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

I'm having some trouble getting the Autowired annotation working.  See these two classes:

```
@Component("upAuthenticationProvider")
public class UPAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO;

    // snip

    public AuthenticationDAO getAuthenticationDAO() {
    return authenticationDAO;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationDAO(
          AuthenticationDAO authenticationDAO) {
    this.authenticationDAO = authenticationDAO;
    }
}
```

and the dependency:

```
@Repository
public class AuthenticationPostgresDAO implements AuthenticationDAO{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    // snip...
}
```

I see this in the logs when the app initializes:

```
08:09:41.268 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'upAuthenticationProvider'
08:09:41.268 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'upAuthenticationProvider'
08:09:41.269 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Found injected element on class [com.mycompany.authentication.UPAuthenticationProvider]: AutowiredFieldElement for private com.mycompany.dao.AuthenticationDAO com.mycompany.authentication.UPAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticationDAO
08:09:41.269 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'upAuthenticationProvider' to allow for resolving potential circular references
08:09:41.271 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'upAuthenticationProvider': AutowiredFieldElement for private com.mycompany.dao.AuthenticationDAO com.mycompnay.authentication.UPAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticationDAO
08:09:41.273 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'AuthenticationPostgresDAO'
08:09:41.273 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'AuthenticationPostgresDAO'
08:09:41.273 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Found injected element on class [com.mycompnay.dao.AuthenticationPostgresDAO]: AutowiredFieldElement for private javax.sql.DataSource com.mycompany.dao.AuthenticationPostgresDAO.dataSource
08:09:41.273 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'authenticationPostgresDAO' to allow for resolving potential circular references
08:09:41.273 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected method of bean 'authenticationPostgresDAO': AutowiredFieldElement for private javax.sql.DataSource com.mycompnay.dao.AuthenticationPostgresDAO.dataSource
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'dataSource'
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'AuthenticationPostgresDAO' to bean named 'dataSource'
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'authenticationPostgresDAO'
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Autowiring by type from bean name 'upAuthenticationProvider' to bean named 'authenticationPostgresDAO'
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'upAuthenticationProvider'
08:09:41.274 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationPostgresDAO'
```

It looks like it's telling me it created the dependency and wired it up, but in my application, I get a NPE when trying to access authencticationPostgresDAO from upAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Do you have: <context:annotation-config/> and <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/> in your applicationContext.xml file?

Comment: @BenSchro10 yes, i have them both set.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is obviously not in the code you show us...
1) How do you access to your instance of upAuthenticationProvider, you should get it from the Spring ApplicationContext.
2) What is the code throwing the NPE? could something else than the DAO be null on the line throwing the exception ?

Comment: I'm using the spring security namespace to supply upAuthenticationProvider to the authentication manager as such:
[code]<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="upAuthenticationProvider" />
  </authentication-manager>[code]

Comment: Sorry - hit enter and then couldn't edit.  Here's what i meant to type:

I'm using the spring security namespace to supply upAuthenticationProvider to the authentication manager as such:
`<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="upAuthenticationProvider" />
  </authentication-manager>`
I'm using `form-login` as well, so I'd assume all the normal activity is taking place to execute the method.

The NPE is happening on a line that uses `authenticationDAO`, But it's a good point. I set a breakpoint on that line and the class member `authenticationDAO` is null at that point.